# notepad++ is there diff highlighting?

Tags: diff, notepad++

Is it possible to highlight diff in notepad++ while keeping java highlighting... or at all?
What im working with is a straight console output ala:

```
-
-                if (model.asMap().get("deanOffice") == null) {
-                    model.addAttribute("deanOffice", deptNames.get(1));
-                }
-            }
+
```

Can you recommend another program which will allow me to view diffs comfortably, when all i have is a console output?

Comment: Notepad++ (v6.1.5) **does** have a diff syntax highlighting. If the file has an appropriate extension (like `.diff` or `.patch`) it is automatically used. Otherwise choose "Language" > "D" > "Diff" from the main menu.

Comment: I nominated this for re-opening, but upon reading carefully I see that it's actually not clear at all what kind of highlighting is desired.

Comment: @KyleStrand I think what OP is getting at is having both diff highlighting and java highlighting. A possible solution would be background highlight for diff and foreground for java (which I don't think actually exists). AndreasFester has the solution for the problem I needed actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try KDiff3 http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/